# Как заменить белый фон?

Tags: android, background, android-drawable

Как проще всего заменить стандартный белый фон в разрабатываемом приложении Android? Каким-нибудь светлым фоном, замостить. Например, вот такой вариант:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Допустим, картинку небольшого размера я закачал в drawable. Теперь хочу ею заполнить весь экран.

Comment: android:background="@drawable/your_image" вы это имеете ввиду?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**drawable/app_background.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:src="@drawable/actual_pattern_image"
        android:tileMode="repeat" />
```

**values/styles.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/app_background</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

Или в корневом элементе макета (предположим, что это LinearLayout):

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/app_background" >
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

В стилях:

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/my_drawable</item>
```

Программно (java):

```
getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.my_drawable);
```

Comment: Благодарю. Попробую.